# Streaming to an iPad

Tags: live-streaming

We have two needs:

1. We want to stream raw audio to an iPad over Bluetooth.
2. We want to stream serialized .jpgs to an iPad over Bluetooth.

In the first case, we don't want any iPad codec to process our audio ... we simply want the iPad app which we will write to receive our audio and pass it to the built-in speakers.

In the second case, we want the iPad app that we will write, to deserialize our .jpg and pass it to the iPad screen. We do want our iPad app to be able to control the size of the .jpg being displayed.

So there are two fundamental questions

1. We need an iPad api to extract the payload from incoming Bluetooth packets so that our iPad app can decide if it's audio or .jpg,
2. We need an iPad api to route our raw audio to the iPad speakers or route our .jpg data to the iPad screen.

Please help ... we need a starting point. Thanks.

Comment: Possible starting point: https://developer.apple.com/

Comment: To Will (moderator) ... with respect, what is ambiguous about my question? We will be having SCO (raw audio) Bluetooth packets arriving at our iPad and we need an api to grab the packet payloads and route them to the iPad's speakers.